# no access denied page when accessing a mysites page

Tags: access-denied, my-site

I currently support a MOSS 2007 farm (iis6). We just notice a strange issue on our mysites web application. if a user trys to access another user's mysites page and does not have access, they will see the following error message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E05 instead of sharepoint's standed "access denied page."

Any clue why this is happening. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We just had this problem and found that the My Site in question was over it's quota. We increased the quota and the problem went away.

For more details visit:
http://www.tcscblog.com/2011/03/16/my-site-unreachable-by-some-users/